# Change title on the tooltip of browser action in a chrome extension app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to change the title on tooltip whenever the brwoser action is clicked. In this case the tool tip says "Proud moment". I want to change it to "Hi". Please look at my code in background.js

These are the resources of the extension app:

Manifest.json

```
{
"name" : "test",
"description" : "positive results",
"version" : "2.0",
"manifest_version" : 2,
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
],

"browser_action" : {

    "default_title" : "Proud Moment",
    "default_popup" : "popup.html"
},

"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
 }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
    function(tab){
    chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title :"Hi"});
});
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <p> Evrything goes here !!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you click the browser action? Does the tooltip change? Do you get any output in the background.js console?

Comment: Once I click on the browser action only the popup.html appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have both a browser action click event callback and a popup.

From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked

> **onClicked**
>
> Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. *This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup.*

Maybe you could send a message from your popup to `background.js` to change the browser action title when the popup opens.

Comment: Thanks it worked ... This is what i added in background,js     chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup : "popup.html"});